# where to find an undershirt gartel?

Tags: minhag, clothing, tzitzis

Looking for a gartel that goes under the shirt to keep tzitzis straight but have only found the large ones that married men wear. where would one find the smaller thinner kind that can go under a shirt?

Comment: Everyone I know uses a [Shabbos Key Belt](http://merkazstam.com/index.php/adjustable-shabbos-key-belt.html) (without the key, obviously).

Comment: Why would that not be problematic on shabbas to wear two belts on top of each other?

Comment: it doesn't go on top of a belt. it goes on top of a tallis katan

Answer (score 3):

Try getting a piece of elastic at a fabric store. Get a long enough piece that you don't have to stretch it too far.
You could also do what some chassidim do for their regular gartlech and use a couple shoelaces tied together (without the aglets).

Comment: walmart sells them: http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?search_query=elastic&ic=16_0&Find=Find&search_constraint=2637

Comment: I've done this and the gartel works great. :) The elastic idea is truly amazing.

Answer (score 1):

you can get them from Judaica World. Here is a link to order from... http://www.judaica-world.com/elastic-bendel-belt.html